# Maximo 7.6 Intergration Automation Script

Tags: automation, maximo

I'm trying to create an Intergration Automation Script for a PUBLISHED Channel which updates a database field.

Basically for WOACTIVITY I just want a field value setting to 1 for the Work Order if the PUBLISHED channel is triggered.

Any ideas or example scripts that anyone has or can help with please? Just can't get it work.

Comment: Can you share with us an example of the script you have now?  What is/isn't happening with it?  It could be just a minor change to what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a SET processing rule on the publish channel?  Processing rules are evaluated every time the channel is activated, and a SET action will let you set an attribute for the parent object to a specified value.  You can [read more about processing rules here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mif.doc/mbs_common/t_defining_processing_rules.html).

Comment: It sounds to me like @matta is wanting the field value set on the record in Maximo. If I'm right, then the problem with this Answer is that it will set the value in the outbound XML, not on the Work Order in Maximo.

Comment: Of course Preacher, looks like I may not have read the question as well as I thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new answer because experience, in case it helps anyone.

If you create an automation script for integration against a Publish Channel and then select External Exit or User Exit there's an implicit variable irData that has access to the MBO being worked on.  You can then use that MBO as you would in any other script.  Note that because you're changing a record that's integrated you'll probably want a skip rule in your publish channel that skips records with your value set or you may run into an infinite publish --> update --> publish loop.

```
woMbo = irData.getCurrentMbo()
woMboSet = woMbo.getThisMboSet()

woMbo.setValue("FIELD", 1)
woMboSet.save()
```